# Android app for photo editing with Flickr support

Tags: android, photography, image-editor

Is there any Android app for photo editing which allows photos from your Flickr account to be edited? I've looked around quite a bit without any luck.

Comment: As I'm not putting my photos "in the cloud", I don't know which app does support this. But to make it easier to find one: I've a [list of apps on Photo Editing](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/foto_edit), containing links to reviews and more. At least that should narrow down the search, as you will have most of the relevant apps on one page.